# Node-acl method "isAllowed" always returns false unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, permissions, acl

I am trying to implement node-acl with mongodb and express to allow control over each document e.g

- User view all documents
- User can only edit/delete their own documents.

I have taken this approach:

1. When user signs up, I use a post save hook to create a user and assign it a role:

   ```
   UserSchema.post('save', function(doc) {
       var roles = doc.roles || [];

       if (!roles.length) {
           roles = ['user'];
       }

       acl.addUserRoles(doc._id.toString(), roles, function(err) {
           console.log(err, 'added user');
       });
   });
   ```
2. Now that the user has been created in the system, they can now create an trip. Like above, I use the post save hook to add the given permissions to the given user over the given resource:

   ```
   TripSchema.post('save', function(trip) {
       acl.allow(trip.user.toString(), '/trips/' + trip._id, '*', function(err) {

       });
   });
   ```
3. I then use a custom simple middleware function to check the given user has access to the given resource with the given permissions:

   ```
   var middleware = function (req, res, next) {

       acl.isAllowed(req.user._id.toString(), req.path, ['put'], function (err, allow) {

           if (allow) {
               next()
           }

           res.status(403).send({});

       });

   };
   ```

However, `allow` is always false and I think it may be to do with what permissions the user has been assigned.

```
    acl.whatResources(req.user._id.toString(), function (err, roles) {
        console.log(err, roles); 

        // roles === { '/trips/56933aedc012523c352d3d85': [ 'put' ] } 
    });
```

From the above I can assume that the user has 'put' as a permission on the '/trips/56933aedc012523c352d3d85' resource

I also tried checking `areAnyRolesAllowed` which should return true if any of the given roles have the right permissions

```
    acl.areAnyRolesAllowed( req.user._id.toString(), '/trips/56933aedc012523c352d3d85', 'put', function(err, allowed)  {
        console.log(err, allowed);

        // allowed === true
    });
```

This only adds more confusion as to why `isAllowed` always returns false

Finally I make further checks with `allowedPermissions` which returns all the allowable permissions a given user have to access the given resources

```
    acl.allowedPermissions(req.user._id.toString(), req.path, function (err, permissions) {
        console.log(err, permissions);

        // permissions === { '/trips/56933aedc012523c352d3d85': [] }
    });
```

From this we can assume that the user does not have any permissions on this particular resource. Why? It appears to conflict with what is returned from `whatResources` so I'm a little confused.

Is there a step I'm missing out where I need to add permissions?

Comment: I have managed to get it to work as expected but only when I pass the user ID as a role to the `addUserRoles` which to me feels wrong. It would mean every user has its own role, is that okay? It seems to go against ACL if there is one user per role.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method in your config file:

```
require('rout/of/your/policy/file').invokeRolesPolicies();
```

If you don't do it, always returns false unexpectedly